# How to run bundle --without in a way that installs gems in multiple groups?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

If you run `bundle --without development test` on this gemfile, it will not install bcrypt because it appears in a group that has development as a member. How could you specify bundle to install bcrypt and not the other groups?

```
gem "rails"

group :production, :development do
  gem "bcrypt"
end

group :development do
  gem "better_errors"
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
end
```

Edit: Alternatively, which is a better way of structuring the file in such a way as I can avoid bcrypt being included in test?

Comment: Doesn't NewRelic perform a no-op when in test environment anyway?

Comment: I just doodled an minimal example gemfile to illustrate the problem. Newrelic might have been a bad choice so imagine it was pagination.

Answer (score 1):

I would add it flat out to the Gemfile, like this:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
```

And then in `test.rb`  simply disable it. See here for details: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/ruby-agent/troubleshooting/controlling-when-ruby-agent-starts

Comment: Lets imagine it's some gem with an external dependency such as nokogiri, I do not want these gems installed at all, which is why I'm specifying without.

Comment: I don't see how you could have Nokogiri in production, but not testing that it's parsing HTML correctly in some form of test. And the same goes for all other gems. 

I'm not saying you should test the gem, but you should test that the output of methods are right, which means that you will need the gem available in test.

Comment: I don't care about testing nokogiri or any gem. This question is about preventing certain gem *groups* from being *installed* on the system at all.